# Ubuntu Upgraded from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS, how do I upgrade libstdc++.so.6 properly?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates, c++

Upon upgrading, my system only booted to terminal mode, and almost nothing worked including **apt** which failed with:

`apt: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference`

I chased that down and found that the new libstdc++.so.6.0.22 apparently didn't link to the right things, but libstdc++.so.6.0.21 does. I found a copy of libstdc++.so.6.0.21 and pointed the libstdc++.so.6 symlink to it, and everything worked again. System boots to GUI, programs run, etc.

However, some updates in Software Updater are failing (including MySQL), and usually when they fail, something has pointed libstdc++.so.6 back to 0.22. When this happens, several programs in my still running Xwindow session refuse to run, like Firefox and AisleRiot Solitare (before I've figured out there's a problem). The moment I point the symlink back to 0.21, everything works again.

I would like to be running on the stable updates of everything, including libstdc++, but it seems I am missing something, or something upgraded out of order and broke the process so I am in a half-upgraded state in the libraries. How do I properly get this upgraded from here?

```
dpkg -S 'libstdc++.6.0.22'
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *libstdc++.6.0.22*
```

Comment: The ...21 version is the current one on my up to date 16.04.  Where did you get the 22 version?

Comment: Did you have any PPAs that might have imported the .22 version? Does `dpkg -S 'libstdc++.so.6.0.22'` shed any light?

Comment: Added dpkg output. No help there, but it is good to hear that .21 is supposed to be the current one.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-all libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```

work for me
or copy ibstdc++.so.6 from other pc.